Styling .dwg CAD Layer with ThinkGeo WPF
I have a WPF application using ThinkGeo's desktop component.   On some .dwg files, the styling is not working as expected.
For example, using the code below:
        var cadOverlay = new LayerOverlay();
        MapView.Overlays.Add("CAD overlay", cadOverlay);

        var cadLayer = new CadFeatureLayer(@"./MyData/CAD/Parcels.DWG");
        cadLayer.StylingType = CadStylingType.EmbeddedStyling;

        cadOverlay.Layers.Add("CAD Drawing", cadLayer);

Results in some .dwg files being styled correctly and matching the CAD file styling.  But with other files, the polygons are rendered as a plain black outline style.
Is there a way to debug or fix this issue?

It may depend on the application used to create your parcels.dwg.  With different providers and versions, sometimes the embedded styling cannot be read properly.  If you provide specifics on the file, I can try to find the root cause.
However, a good workaround is to just switch to StandardStyling and programmatically style the .dwg.   The code below would add a simple blue line style on your parcels:
// use the CadStylingType.StandardStyling
cadLayer.StylingType = CadStylingType.StandardStyling;
cadLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.DefaultLineStyle = new LineStyle(new GeoPen(GeoColors.Blue, 2));
cadLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.ApplyUntilZoomLevel = ApplyUntilZoomLevel.Level20;

Of course, if your CAD file has points or polygons, you could also use a PointStyle or AreaStyle.   You can learn more about programmatically creating styles at ThinkGeo Basics: Styles.
